# MySQL query JOIN with 2 tables and multiple entries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to do a MySQL JOIN query to grab the content from two tables.

This is what Table A looks like:

Table A

```
ID  |  ISBN   |  Type
----------------------
12  | 0338566 | book
15  | 6656565 | post
16  | 9435644 | book
20  | 8525446 | book
```

And Table B

```
ID  |  tableA_id  |    Key      |  Value
---------------------------------------------
1   |     12      |    Author   |  John Doe
2   |     12      |    Title    |  Book Title 1
3   |     16      |    Title    |  Book Title 2
4   |     20      |    Author   |  John Doe
5   |     20      |    Title    |  Book Title 3
```

I am trying to build my SQL statement to output all book data, something like:

```
ISBN    |    Author    |    Title
-------------------------------------
0338566 |   John Doe   | Book Title 1
9435644 |              | Book Title 2
8525446 |   John Doe   | Book Title 3
```

After looking up SQL JOIN statements, this is what I came up with:

```
SELECT tableA.ISBN, tableB.value
FROM tableA, tableB  
WHERE tableA.ID = tableB.tableA_id AND tableA.type = “book” AND  (tableB.key = "title" OR tableB.author = "store_selector" )
```

The query is bringing back just 2 columns, because I'm only referencing tableB.value once, even though I need to grab both values within it (title and author).

How would I properly structure this query?

Comment: I recommend you to properly structure your database rather than query. Add `Author` and `Title` columns to `tableB`

Comment: @umka This is actually the way Wordpress stores data for posts, in the wp_posts table and wp_postmeta table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not the best way to solve this problem, but I would join tableB two times with aliases and pick the value as needed like this :

```
SELECT tableA.ISBN, author.value as Author, title.Value as Title
FROM tableA
left join tableB author 
    on tableA.ID = author.tableA_id  
    and author.key = "Author"
left join tableB title 
    on tableA.ID = title.tableA_id 
    and title.key = "Title"
where tableA.type = “book”
```

PS: this data model looks terrible, I'd rather update it and store titles and authors in two different tables

Comment: This is actually the way Wordpress stores data for posts, in the wp_posts table and wp_postmeta table. This isn't my dat model unfortunately.

Comment: there is probably a reason behind this choice then :) let me know if that query works for you.

Comment: PhpMyAdmin is giving me the following error:  #1054 - Unknown column 'author.value' in 'field list'. There is no table called author... is that why?

Comment: in this case, `author` is an alias, not a table. in your model, `Value` is noted with a capital `V` and your error message indicates you wrote a lowercase `v`, maybe this is the reason of this error

Comment: Same issue with a capital V. So the above statement was my compressed version of a Wordpress table... I can show you the real query I'm using.. it's:

Comment: SELECT wp_posts.post_title, store_selector.value as Store_selector, card_owner.Value as Card_owner
FROM wp_posts
left join wp_postmeta store_selector 
    on wp_posts.ID = store_selector.post_id  
    and store_selector.key = "store_selector"
left join wp_postmeta card_owner 
    on wp_posts.ID = card_owner.wp_posts_id 
    and card_owner.key = "card_owner"
where wp_posts.post_type = “card”

Comment: you still have a mix of lowercase/uppercase in the fields list: `store_selector.value` and `card_owner.Value` - if I remember well, mysql is case sensitive

Comment: I've changed it from caps to no caps and still same error. Would you be able to provide me the query with the proper casing? I must be doing something wrong here: SELECT wp_posts.post_title, store_selector.Value as Store_selector, card_owner.Value as Card_owner
FROM wp_posts
left join wp_postmeta Store_selector 
    on wp_posts.ID = Store_selector.post_id  
    and Store_selector.key = "store_selector"
left join wp_postmeta Card_owner 
    on wp_posts.ID = Card_owner.wp_posts_id 
    and Card_owner.key = "card_owner"
where wp_posts.post_type = “card”

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80597/discussion-between-pascamel-and-steeped).

Comment: Note, for upcoming visitors: at the end, the column name is `wp_postmeta.meta_value`